# How do I set the exact same margins to all sides of the page?

Tags: margins

I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but sadly, none of which solved my problem.

I want an A4 page with the textbox exactly 10mm margins to all sides (to the edges of the paper). But everytime I try something like

```
top=10mm, bottom=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm            // or
tmargin=10mm, bmargin=10mm, lmargin=10mm, rmargin=10mm  // or
margin=10mm

etc.
```

with `geometry` it destroys my page as soon as i set it to something other than 1in.

**Pic 1** (messed up):

[image]

**Pic 2** (default):

[image]

I also tried setting `total`, `heigth`, `width`, `hmarginratio`, `vmarginratio`, `marginparsep`, `bindingoffset`, `footskip`, `textwidth`, `textheight`, `\setlrmarginsandblock`, `\setulmarginsandblock` ... and a few others.

**Code for Pic 1:**

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    ngerman
]{minimal}
% i use minimal because i don't need header, footer, page number etc.
% i just need a simple textbox

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[
    top=10mm,
    bottom=10mm,
    left=10mm,
    right=10mm
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8] % corrected

\end{document}
```

**Code for Pic 2:**

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    ngerman
]{minimal}
% i use minimal because i don't need header, footer, page number etc.
% i just need a simple textbox

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8] % corrected

\end{document}
```

I use Texmaker on Ubuntu with TexLive (installed because of an error with ngerman)

Maybe notable: everytime i use `heightrounded` i get an `Arithmetic overflow`

---

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for your answers! I finally *solved* my problem. With ShareLaTeX i get the same result as you (and what i want). I also tried different other clients (LyX, gedit-latex-plugin and TeXstudio). LyX and gedit have the same problem, but TeXstudio finally works after i made a full install of TeXLive. Still don't know whats wrong, but at least it works.

Comment: `\lipsum{1-8}` is wrong. It should be `\lipsum[1-8]`. Your 'Pic 1' example compiles fine for me with correct margins.

Comment: *Don't* ever use `minimal`. It is *not* for minimal examples.

Answer (score 1):

No problem here either. I just simplified the code to set margins and used  the `showframe` option of geometry:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ngerman]{minimal}
% I use minimal because i don't need header, footer, page number etc.
% I just need a simple textbox
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=10mm, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compiles fine for me. (this was done using ShareLaTeX)

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    ngerman
]{minimal}
% i use minimal because i don't need header, footer, page number etc.
% i just need a simple textbox

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[
    top=10mm,
    bottom=10mm,
    left=10mm,
    right=10mm
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8] % Not \lipsum{1-8}

\end{document}
```

[image]